# If you have only one force acting on a particle, can the work on that particle ever be negative?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, work

Looking at a few problems that are prefaced by *Suppose a particle of mass m moves under the influence of a force field along a space curve whose position vector is given by* a function r with x, y, z components.

I got v and a, and then did the Fdr integral to get the work, but on a few I'm getting negative work. Should that be possible?

Ex: F = 24i + 24tj -48{t^2}k from t=1 to t=2

After the integral I had

24t +12t^2 - 16t^3   from t=1 to t=2

Which gave me -52.

Comment: Yes, it slows the particle.

Answer (score 2):

It can absolutely happen.

However, it wont happen in a case where the initial conditions are a standstill, where velocity = 0 for all particles.  In this case, the only source of acceleration will indeed be the force, and it will always end up doing positive work.  However, this is a very special case.

A counterexample might be a spring decelerating a ball that starts with some initial velocity.  It should be quite clear that the spring is doing negative work.  This happened because the initial conditions ensured the velocity of the ball remained always pointed towards the spring, while the spring opposed its motion.

Answer (score 0):

Work is defined as dot product of 2 vectors. $\Delta w = \mathbf {F.\Delta x}$.

And dot product is not necessarily positive.

Comment: What is $\Delta$w?

Answer (score 0):

> If you have only one force acting on a particle, can the work on that particle ever be negative?

Yes. Consider a ball that you’ve thrown upward. After it left your hand, gravity is the only force on it, if we neglect air drag.  Initially it’s moving opposite to gravity. Gravity is doing negative work on it, slowing it down. Once it stops going up and starts going down, gravity is doing positive work on it, making it speed up.